# Inserir botão em frente à uma paginação

Tags: html5, css3, angular

[image: o layout ficaria com o botão do lado dos numeros da paginação]Criei uma paginação pra que o retorno de minha API ficasse com melhor desempenho no momento que é renderizado na tela, a questão de ajuste tudo ok, porém, nessa tela eu trabalho com TAB, e tem uma TAB que coloquei uma condição para que aparecesse um botão somente nela, ao fim, perto do layout de paginação. O problema é que eu preciso por esse botão ao lado dessa paginação (na mesma linha) e não consigo. Tentei diminuir o width, forçar o inline no css mas sem sucesso. Alguém pode me auxiliar?

Segue o código:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 ">

    <nb-card [nbSpinner]="pendenciaSintetico.length < 1" nbSpinnerStatus="success">
      <nb-card-header>Pendência de Físico</nb-card-header>
      <nb-card-body>
        <nb-tabset class="size-fonte" fullWidth (changeTab)="findPendencia($event)">
          <nb-tab *ngFor="let p of pendenciaSintetico" [tabTitle]="p.status_time_line" [active]="p.ativo"
            badgeText="{{p.contador_contratos_time_line}}" badgeStatus="success">



            <div class="container">


              <table class="tabela" [nbSpinner]="pendencia.length < 1" nbSpinnerStatus="success" equalColumnsWidth>
                <thead>

                  <tr>
                    <th class="text-left">Proposta</th>
                    <th class="text-left">Cliente</th>
                    <th class="text-left">Agente</th>
                    <th class="text-left">Operação</th>
                    <th class="text-left">Órgão</th>
                    <th class="text-left">Data</th>
                    <th class="text-left">Dias Pendentes</th>
                    <th *ngIf="p.codigo_status_time_line == 0 || p.codigo_status_time_line == 1" class="text-left">Ação
                    </th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr *ngFor="let i of pendencia | slice: pageSize | slice: 0:itemsPerPage">
                    <td class="size-fonte">{{i.proposta}} </td>
                    <td class="size-fonte">{{i.nome_cliente}}</td>
                    <td class="size-fonte">
                      <span nbTooltip="Nome Digitador">{{i.nome_agente}}</span><br>
                      <span nbTooltip="Nome Fantasia">{{i.nome_loja}}</span><br>
                      <span nbTooltip="Nome Regional">{{i.nome_regional}}</span><br>
                    </td>
                    <td class="size-fonte">
                      <span nbTooltip="Tipo Operação">{{i.tipo_operacao}}</span><br>
                      <span nbTooltip="Produto Corban">{{i.nome_produto_corban}}</span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="size-fonte">
                      <span nbTooltip="Nome Convênio">{{i.nome_convenio}}</span><br>
                      <span nbTooltip="Nome Instituição">{{i.nome_instituicao}}</span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="size-fonte">
                      <span
                        nbTooltip="Data Entrada Operação">{{i.data_entrada_operacao | moment: 'DD/MM/YYYY'}}</span><br>
                      <span nbTooltip="Data Status">{{i.data_status | moment: 'DD/MM/YYYY'}}</span></td>
                    <td class="size-fonte-center">
                      <button nbButton status="info" outline [size]="tiny"
                        nbTooltip="Quantidade de dias pendentes">{{i.dias_pendentes}}</button>
                    </td>
                    <td class="size-fonte">
                      <button *ngIf="p.codigo_status_time_line == 0" nbButton status="success" [size]="medium" outline
                        (click)="enviarPreBordero(i.pk)" nbTooltip="Enviar proposta para Pré Borderô">
                        <i class="fa fa-share color"></i>
                      </button>
                      <button *ngIf="p.codigo_status_time_line == 1" nbButton status="danger" [size]="medium" outline
                        (click)="retirarPreBordero(i.pk)" nbTooltip="Retirar proposta do Pré Borderô">
                        <i class="fa fa-reply color"></i>
                      </button>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
            <button *ngIf="p.codigo_status_time_line == 1" class="btnGerar" nbButton status="success" size="medium" hero
              (click)="gerarBordero($event)" nbTooltip="Clique para gerar borderô"> Gerar Borderô
            </button>
            <button *ngIf="p.codigo_status_time_line == 1" class="btnGerar" nbButton status="success" size="medium" hero
              (click)="gerarBordero($event)" nbTooltip="Clique para gerar borderô"> Gerar Borderô
            </button>
            <button class="btnGerar" nbButton status="success" size="medium" hero (click)="gerarBordero($event)"
              nbTooltip="Clique para gerar borderô"> Gerar Borderô
            </button>
          </nb-tab>
        </nb-tabset>
        <div *ngFor="let p of pendenciaSintetico">
          <ngb-pagination *ngIf="p.codigo_status_time_line == 1" [collectionSize]="pendencia.length" #numPages
            [maxSize]="15" [pageSize]="itemsPerPage" [(page)]="currentPage" (pageChange)="onPageChange(currentPage)">
          </ngb-pagination>
        </div>
      </nb-card-body>
    </nb-card>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cara tem como vc editar a pergunta é incluir um pronta de com esta na sua tela e indicar como quer que fique?

Comment: Percebi isso e coloquei uma imagem pra demonstrar. No caso ficaria na mesma linha que os números da paginação. Mas se mantendo pelo lado direito no final, com o float: right.

Comment: Man, vc está utlizando 2 framewroks Css pra Angular juntos, o Angular Bootstrap e Nebular, é isso mesmo?

Comment: sim, tem umas limitações no NB, infelizmente peguei o projeto em andamento dessa forma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara tem umas coisas estranhas ai, vc parece que está usando Bootstrap, e colocando tudo dentro de um `Card`, mas nem vou entrar nesse assunto, pq não importa muito pro resultado final...

Repare que vc deve ter uma `div` com classe `row`, ela já é um *container* `flex` por definição do Bootstrap. Então basta adicionar nessa `row` a classe `justify-content-end` para alinha o que estiver dentro a direita. O `button` deve estar fora do componente de paginação e seu resultado será como abaixo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-end">
        <nav class="mr-auto" aria-label="Page navigation example">
            <ul class="pagination mb-0">
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Previous</a></li>
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm ml-2">Primary</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Documentação da paginação do Bootstrap https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/pagination/

Comment: os elementos estão "colados", um deveria ficar a direita o outro a esquerda. Não consegui retirar isso...

Comment: @WandersonBueno na nav de paginação coloque a classe mr-auto veja na edição que fiz na resposta

Comment: ainda continua...

Comment: @WandersonBueno tente criar um ambiente de teste só com o compenten de paginação e seu botão e veja se funciona. Se funcionar corretamente é pq tem algo no restante do seu código que está atrapalhando as coisas. Se aqui no exemplo funciona era para funcionar ai tb. Reveja sua estrutura do HTML e as Classes para vc se vc está fazendo tudo certo. **Veja que dentro da ROW só tem 2 filhos diretos, a uma NAV e um BUTTON...**

Comment: Este código não vai servir, o dele não é paginação normal, é um componente Angular, que muito provavelmente por padrão possui um display:block no elemento.

Comment: @LeAndrade pode até ser, mas quando vc tem dois elementos Block, dentro de um container Flex, eles ficam por padrão um ao lado do outro, e não um embaixo do outro. Então duas Col, dentro de um ROW as COL vão ficar uma ao lado da outra, e não uma abaixo da outra entende. Mas realmente, pode ser que o componente de paginação dele seja diferente, mas como ele está usando o BS, peguei o padrão do BS

Comment: Ahan, certinho @hugocsl , disse isso mais pra ressaltar mesmo o que ele está tentando fazer. Ele está utilizando este componente de paginação que é do Angular Bootstrap dentro de outro framweork css que é o Nebular que tbm utiliza Bootstrap, deve estar um se sobrepondo o outro.

Comment: @LeAndrade então deve ser conflito de CSS mesmo, fica complicado simular o problema dele nessas condições

Comment: Não deu certo, está alinhado mas ambos ficam colados.

Comment: @WandersonBueno agora está alinhando um de cada lado da tela? Eles estão colado onde? Vc pode usar as classes de margin e padding do próprio Bootstrap para corrigir isso da uma olhada aqui que vai te ajudar bastante https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/

Comment: Valeu! Deu certo aqui, consegui por cada qual em um lado! Obrigado =)

Comment: @WandersonBueno legal que deu certo ai!! Se vc acha que a resposta te ajudou de alguma forma considere marca-la como aceita nesse ícone ✔ abaixo das setinhas ao lado da resposta ;)